# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected \'?>\', expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have everything correct and I have closed `?>` the *php* tag and it still shows the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected \'?>\', expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

This is my code:

```php
<?php

class IWP_MMB_ErrorLog extends IWP_MMB_Core {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }


    function get_errorLog($args) {
        $myfile = fopen(ini_get('error_log'), "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
        // Output one line until end-of-file
        while (!feof($myfile)) {
            $string = fgets($myfile);
            $ar = explode("]", $string);
            if (!empty($ar[0])) {
                $remove = trim($ar[0], "[");
                $remove1 = trim($remove, "UTC");
            }
            if (!empty($ar[1]) && !empty($ar[0])) { 
                $error_data[] = array(
                    'date' => $remove1,
                    'content' => $ar[1],
                );
            }
        }
        fclose($myfile);
        return $error_data; 
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message you get!

Comment: actually the closing `?>` is redundant and MIGHT cause problems with any kind of header directives...

Comment: The closing PHP tag (`?>`) is indeed, not needed, if there isn't anything else after it. It does not cause any kind of problems by itself; the presence of whitespace characters (spaces, new lines) after it causes the header problems. It's a good practice to not mix `HTML` and `PHP` in the same file and if you follow it then the next step is to get rid of the closing PHP tag in the PHP files.

Comment: The error indicates that you have not closed a `}` somewhere. I cannot see where in what you posted, triple check your own local code.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem while using NetBeans. The file looks perfectly fine, but I get the same error as you. I suppose NetBeans needs some configuration, but what helps is just creating a new file, copy paste everything that's inside and rename the file... Dirty solution but works...